# Pass parameters to a callback function of a elasticsearch javascript api search request

Tags: javascript, callback, elasticsearch, promise

I've got a function that asks for an aggregation for each word given by the user and then draws a chart.

I would like to know in the callback what was the value of the variable i of my loop when the request was sent.

How can I pass the variable i in the predefined parameters fixed by the elasticsearch API ?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    client.search({
        index: 'twitter',
        type: "status",
        size : 10,
        body: 
        {
            query: {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"query_string": {
                            "fields" : ["text"],
                            "default_operator" : "AND",
                            "query" : $scope.motsCompares[i]
                        }},
                        {"range": {
                            "created_at": {
                                "gte": moment().subtract(duration, key).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                            }
                        }}
                    ]
                }
            },
            aggs : {
                "frequence_mots" : {
                    "date_histogram" : {
                        "field" : "created_at",
                        "interval" : "day",
                        "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
                        "min_doc_count" : 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function traiterResultat(body) {

        // I would like to use i from the loop here to get the right word in my array ($scope.motsCompares[i])

    }, function (error) {
            console.trace(error.message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the advent of `fn.bind()`, this sort of thing required a closure or other approaches so horrible I won't even mention them.

Since ECMAScript 5, you can exploit the "currying" characteristic of `fn.bind()` to pass `i` immediately and `body` later, when the promise chain rips down its success path.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        client.search({
            // ...
        }).then(function (i, body) {
            //.then()'s callback is an intermediate function returned by .bind().
            // `i` here is the loop's `i` that was bound-in by .bind().
            //`body` is passed to the intermediate function later, when the promise chain rips down its success path.
        }.bind(null, i), function (error) {
            console.trace(error.message);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

You can change `null` in `.bind(null, i)` to any object you want to be `this` inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Use another function to create your callback:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  client.search({
                  index: 'twitter',
                  type: "status",
                  size : 10,
                  body:
                  {
                    query: {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {"query_string": {
                            "fields" : ["text"],
                            "default_operator" : "AND",
                            "query" : $scope.motsCompares[i]
                          }},
                          {"range": {
                            "created_at": {
                              "gte": moment().subtract(duration, key).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                            }
                          }}
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    aggs : {
                      "frequence_mots" : {
                        "date_histogram" : {
                          "field" : "created_at",
                          "interval" : "day",
                          "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
                          "min_doc_count" : 0
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }).then(createCallback(i), function (error) {
                          console.trace(error.message);
                        });
}

function createCallback(i){
  return function traiterResultat(body) {

    // use i from the loop here to get the right word in my array ($scope.motsCompares[i])

  }
}
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you. So a callback function has an access to its direct parent's context, that's the idea ?

Comment: @Ganoninc if he solved your issue - consider accepting this answer.

Comment: Yes do accept the answer :). To answer your second question - each new function creates a new scope. And any variables from an outer scope can be 'closed over' in the inner scope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures